# Java メンバ変数を参照しているメンバ変数の初期化について

Tags: java

まず、以下のようなプログラムがあります。

```
public class Test {

   public Test(int value){
        num = value;
   }

   private int num;

   private String str = "value:" + num;

   public void aaa(){
      System.out.println(str);
   }
}
```

Testクラスインスタンス生成時に、引数として「5」を渡した場合、
aaa()の出力結果で、「value:5」と出てほしいのですが、現在は「value:0」となってしまいます。

解決方法の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願い致します。

Comment: このプログラムはコンパイルが通りますか？`private String static str2 = "value:" + num;`の部分はstaticの指定箇所がおかしいのとstatic変数からinstance変数参照しているのでコンパイルエラーになりそうです。

Comment: ご指摘、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[初期化子やコンストラクタの実行タイミング](http://minor.hatenablog.com/entry/20101122/1290437595) は、まずクラスロード時点でstatic変数の初期化が実行され、その後にコンストラクタによるインスタンス生成が行われます。

`str`変数が1度作成されると、その後に`num`の値を変更しても`str`の値は変わりません。
例えば以下の対応方法が考えられます。

```
//方法1. numと一緒にstrも初期化
public Test(int value) {
    num = value;
    str = "value:" + num;
}
//方法2. numを設定するメソッドを作ってnumと一緒にstrも初期化
public Test(int value) {
    setNum(value);
}
private setNum(int value) {
    num = value;
    str = "value:" + num;
}
//方法3. numもstatic変数にして、動的にstrを生成するためのgetStrメソッドを作る
private static int num;
private static String getStr() {
    return "value:" + num; //この方法ならインスタンス初期化時に更新されたnumが反映される
}
```

Comment: ご返答ありがとう御座います。static変数は再設定するしかないということで、理解致しました。

Answer (score 0):

payanecoさんの回答で解決方法については提示されているので、`value:0`が出力される理由について記載します。
[payanecoさんのリンク先](http://minor.hatenablog.com/entry/20101122/1290437595)に詳細な説明がありますが、このプログラムでの初期化順序は以下の通りです。

1. インスタンス生成前
   ・numが0で初期化される
   ・strが"value:0"で初期化される
2. インスタンス生成時(コンストラクタ)
   ・numに引数valueの値(5)が代入される

なのでstatic変数、instance変数に関係なく初期化時にstrに設定された値("value:0")を変更していない為、`value:0`が出力されてしまいます。